# How to access data on server side using express that is sent by client as part of put request

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express

Following is my angular http put request

```
postRequest(data) : Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:5050",data).pipe(map(this.dataHandler));
  }
```

When i make this call following method is being called on server side:

```
app.put("/",function(request,response){
    response.send("Put request received successfully");
})
```

I want to retrieve the data that is being sent from client as part of put request on server side in express. 
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is data? a JSON payload, form-data? can you put a screenshot of the request on the browser dev console?

Comment: Data is just a numeric value being passed      Local
data
:
5
this
:
ApiServiceService
http
:
Http {_backend: XHRBackend, _defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions}
__proto__
:
Object
Closure (./src/app/api-service.service.ts)
Window
Global

Comment: Still, show me the request, depending on the content-type the parsing is done different on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should use `put` instead of `post` if you want to perform a `PUT` request.

```
this.http.put(...)
```

Then on your server side, you can use `body-parser` to parse the request data, and use it on your middleware

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
/* ... */
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // If you're sending a JSON payload
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.text()); // You're sending text/plain

/* ... */
app.put("/",function(request, response){
    console.log(request.body); // Data is inside body
    response.send("Put request received successfully");
});
```

You need to send: `Content-Type: application/json` for `bodyParser.json()` to work, without it, your JSON payload won't be parsed, or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for `bodyParser.urlencoded()`

> The bodyParser object exposes various factories to create middlewares.
>   All middlewares will populate the req.body property with the parsed
>   body when the Content-Type request header matches the type option, or
>   an empty object ({}) if there was no body to parse, the Content-Type
>   was not matched, or an error occurred.

In your specific case you're sending `Content-Type: text/plain` so just use:

```
app.use(bodyParser.text());
```

Comment: I can only send data in json or as part of url?

Comment: No, in any way you want, the parsing is different for every type. That's why I'm asking you to show me how are you sending it. **so please, show me the request on the developers console**, or as `curl`

Comment: That's not the request on the developers console, go to `xhr` and there you will see the request.

Comment: Following is the request : curl 'http://localhost:5050/' -X OPTIONS -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT' -H 'Origin: http://localhost:4200' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --compressed

Comment: That's the OPTIONS, no data is being send, show me the `PUT` request.

Comment: following may be the request : curl "http://localhost:5050/" -X PUT -H "Origin: http://localhost:4200" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36" -H "content-type: text/plain" -H "Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*" -H "Referer: http://localhost:4200/" -H "Connection: keep-alive" --data-binary "5" --compressed

Comment: Check updated answer, use:  `app.use(bodyParser.text());`